# Blocking specific USB drives on MacOS

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension

I need to block specific USB drives on MacOS. I found two methods.

1. Use Disk Arbitration framework and register approval callback.(user mode)
2. Use MAC policy API in kernel extension and register mpo_mount_check_mount callback.(kernel mode)

In user mode, I can get a kDADiskDescriptionDeviceVendorKey which is the vender id of USB drive. I'm wondering how I can get the same information in mpo_mount_check_mount callback or some other API I don't know. The MAC policy API is undocumented and browsing the XNU source code is extremely challenging for a new MacOS developer.

This is a screenshot from IORegistryExplorer. Could I get this information from a kernel extension using MACF or other APIs? Thanks!
[image]

I can use DiskArbitration and IOKit frameworks to get vender id in user mode, but I cannot use the same code in kernel extension.
This is my code.

```
int GetVenderId(DADiskRef dsk, int *vid)  
{  
    io_service_t ioService;  
    CFTypeRef vendorid;  

    ioService = DADiskCopyIOMedia(dsk);  

    if (0 != ioService)  
    {  
        vendorid = IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty(ioService, kIOServicePlane, CFSTR("idVendor"), NULL, kIORegistryIterateParents | kIORegistryIterateRecursively);  
        if(0 != vendorid)  
        {  
            if (CFNumberGetValue(vendorid, kCFNumberIntType, vid))  
            {  
                return 0;  
            }  

            CFRelease(vendorid);  
        }  

        IOObjectRelease(ioService);  
    }  

    return 1;  
}
```

Comment: I will answer your core question when I find some time, but note that Apple explicitly does not support 3rd party MAC policy kexts; the ABI may change without notice (and frequently does between macOS releases) and your kext may stop loading altogether. I don't recommend building anything new on the MAC framework.

Comment: If you wish to go the kernel route, you also have a third option, which would be a driver that matches USB mass storage devices with a higher priority than Apple's own driver. This is at least well supported, although kexts are likely to be deprecated eventually. The technique should also work with the new DriverKit however.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a relevant question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249719/using-kauth-api-in-macos-kernel-extension?r=SearchResults  I tried to implement DLP functionality using Kauth API,  but when it comes to folder copying, system seems to ignore my return code from callback function. I cannot find another callback function which I can use to prevent that.

Comment: For MACF, I found that I can use mpo_vnode_check_create callback to prevent folder copying. I have no idea how I can do the same thing with Kauth.

Comment: BTW, if I use MACF in my kext, could I get my kext notarized successfully? AFAIK, notarization and app review are two different things.